# How to send push notifications for iOS in Delphi FireMonkey

Tags: ios, delphi, apple-push-notifications, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I am a newbie in iOS development in FireMonkey. I need a simple solution to notify the devices that an event occurred.

Does something like Android's push notification exist and can be used with FireMonkey?

Comment: Natively, you have APN (Apple Push Notificatons). You also have local notifications.

Comment: @MarcusAdams an example on how to use

Answer (score 0):

You should use APN (Apple Push Notification).
There's a great material from Luis Felipe's Blog. Link here:

http://lfgonzalez.visiblogs.com/2014/11/radstudio-xe6xe7-remote-push-notifications-gcm-y-apns/

I hope it helps!

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks